# A real $n \times n$ matrix $A$ satisfies $Ax \cdot Ay = x \cdot y$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb R^n$ iff $|Ax| = |x|$ for all $x$ in $\mathbb R^n$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Prove that a real $n \times n$ matrix $A$ satisfies $Ax \cdot Ay = x \cdot y$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb R^n$ iff $|Ax| = |x|$ for all $x$ in
> $\mathbb R^n$.

Just want to confirm: when a problem doesn't explicitly state the inner product and norm for $\mathbb R^n$, do I just assume the inner product and the Euclidean norm? Moreover, how can I solve the right to left direction? I'm trying to use the polarization identity, but I'm stuck here:

$x \cdot y = \frac{1}{4}(|x+y|^2 - |x-y|^2) = \frac{1}{4}((x+y)\cdot(x+y) - (x-y)\cdot(x-y)) = \frac{1}{4}(x \cdot x + 2y \cdot x + y\cdot y - (x \cdot x - 2y \cdot x + y \cdot y)) = \frac{1}{4}(Ax \cdot Ax + 2y \cdot x + Ay\cdot Ay - (Ax \cdot Ax - 2y \cdot x + Ay \cdot Ay))$

The problem is the $y\cdot x$ term because I need that to be $Ay \cdot Ax$ to use the polarization again on $Ay,Ax$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, assume the Euclidean norm. If $Ax\cdot Ay=x\cdot y$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ then in particular for $x=y$ you get $|Ax|^2=|x|^2$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Conversely, if $|Ax|=|x|$ for all $x$ then, using the polarization identity, for every $x,y$
$$x\cdot y=\frac{1}{4}(|x+y|^2-|x-y|^2)=\frac{1}{4}(|A(x+y)|^2-|A(x-y)|^2)=Ax\cdot Ay$$
where in the middle equality we are using the assumption that $|Aw|=|w|$ for all $w$.